# Indexing array from negative number in Rust

Tags: arrays, rust

I am attempting to implement indexing from negative numbers on a four dimensional array in rust

```
use std::slice::SliceIndex;
use std::ops::Index;
use num::Complex;

struct Cresult {
    nin: i32,
    nout: i32,
    two_s_nucl: i32,
    arr: Array4D<Complex<f64>>,
}
impl std::ops::Index<[usize; 4]> for Cresult {
    type Output =&Complex<f64>;
    let offset0: usize = 5;
    let offset1: usize = 5;
    let offset2: usize = 5;
    let offset3: usize = 5;
    fn index(&self, idx: [usize; 4]) ->&&Complex<f64>{
        // or as appropriate for row- or column-major data       
        &self.arr[(idx[0]+offset0, idx[1]+offset1, idx[2]+offset2, idx[3]+offset3)]
    }
}

fn init_result(nin: i32, nout: i32, two_s_nucl: i32) -> Cresult {
    let results_arr = multiarray::Array4D::new(
        [
            nin as usize,
            nout as usize,
            (2 * two_s_nucl + 1) as usize,
            (2 * two_s_nucl + 1) as usize,
        ],
        Complex::new(0.0 as f64, 0.0 as f64),
    );
    let out = Cresult {
        nin: nin,
        nout: nout,
        two_s_nucl: two_s_nucl,
        arr: results_arr,
    };
    return out;

fn main(){
    let test = init_result(2, 2, 3);
    println!("{}", test.arr[(1,1,1,1])];

}
```

Right now I running the above code gives me two errors:

```
error[E0046]: not all trait items implemented, missing: `index` in implementation
```

And

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Wrapped<[usize; 4]>: From<({integer}, {integer}, {integer}, {integer})>` is not satisfied
```

What are the best ways to fix these errors?

Changing the `test.arr` call to:

```
    let one: usize = 1;
    println!("{}", test.arr[(usize,usize,usize,usize)]);
```

Fixes this second error, but this doesn't seems like a great solution.

For the second error the compiler recommends:

```
help: implement the missing item: `fn index(&self, _: Idx) -> &<Self as Index<Idx>>::Output { todo!() }`
```

But I am not sure how exactly to do this.

Comment: You cannot declare `let` in a trait implementation.

Comment: These look more like `const` than variables to me.

Comment: I get totally different compilation errors, including syntax errors on unclosed delimiters. Could you fix up your code so that compiling it results in the error you are reporting?

Comment: Can you share a https://www.rustexplorer.com link please? To copy the link, press the left-most button in the upper right hand corner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve my own problem. I had a typing issue in `impl std::ops::Index`. There weren't any major structural issues.

```
extern crate multiarray;
use multiarray::Array4D;
use std::ops::Index;

struct Cresult {
    nin: i32,
    nout: i32,
    two_s_nucl: i32,
    arr: Array4D<Complex<f64>>,
}

impl std::ops::Index<[i32;4]> for Cresult {
    type Output =Complex<f64>;
    fn index(&self, idx:[i32;4])->&Self::Output{//&&Complex<f64>{ 
      
        assert!(idx[0] < self.nin);
        assert!(idx[1] < self.nout);

        assert!(idx[2]<self.two_s_nucl+1);
        assert!(idx[2]>=-1*self.two_s_nucl);

        assert!(idx[3]<self.two_s_nucl+1);
        assert!(idx[3]>=-1*self.two_s_nucl);
         &self.arr[[
             idx[0] as usize,
             idx[1] as usize,
             (idx[2]+self.two_s_nucl) as usize,
             (idx[3]+self.two_s_nucl) as usize,
         ]]
    }
}
impl std::ops::Index<[i32;4]> for Cresult {
    type Output =Complex<f64>;
    fn index(&self, idx:[i32;4])->&Self::Output{
   
        assert!(idx[0]<self.nin);
        assert!(idx[1] < self.nout);

        assert!(idx[2]<self.two_s_nucl+1);
        assert!(idx[2]>=-1*self.two_s_nucl);

        assert!(idx[3]<self.two_s_nucl+1);
        assert!(idx[3]>=-1*self.two_s_nucl);
         &self.arr[[
             idx[0] as usize,
             idx[1] as usize,
             (idx[2]+self.two_s_nucl) as usize,
             (idx[3]+self.two_s_nucl) as usize,
         ]]
    }
}

fn main(){
    let test = init_result(2, 2, 3);
    let one: [i32; 4]= [0,1,3,-3];
    println!("{}",test[one]);

}
```